# Comparar data atual com javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Estou comparando a data de hoje com a data de hoje dessa forma:

```js
if (new Date() > new Date('07/04/2017'))
{
     alert('Hoje é maior que hoje?')
}
```

Como é possível hoje ser maior que hoje?

Comment: Suponho que o objetivo seja comparar se uma data é maior que outra, @LucasCosta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como todos já falaram, o motivo desta comparação é o horário que está sendo utilizado. Caso deseje comparar somente as datas, você pode utilizar o [toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString).

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var hoje = new Date().toDateString();
var data2 = new Date('07/04/2017').toDateString();

console.log(hoje)
console.log(data2)

if (hoje > data2) {
  console.log('Hoje é maior que data2')
} else if (hoje == data2) {
  console.log('Hoje é igual a data2')
} else {
  console.log('Hoje é menor que data2')
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Isso é porque `new Date()` conta também a hora atual, criando uma data a partir da *string* a hora fica zerada.

```js
console.log(new Date());
console.log(new Date('07/04/2017'));

if (new Date() > new Date('07/04/2017'))
{
    console.log('Hoje é maior que hoje?')
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Quando corres `new Date('07/04/2017')` e assumindo que a formatação é aceite isso vai dar a hora exata no inicio desse dia, ao milisegundo.

Quando corres somente `new Date()` isso vai dar a hora exata no momento em que é corrido, ou seja algures depois do dia ter começado.

Se separares isso em partes pode reparar melhor:

```js
var inicio = new Date('07/04/2017');
var agora = new Date();

console.log('Diferença em milisegundos', agora - inicio);
console.log(
  'Diferença em h:m', [
    Math.floor((agora - inicio) / 1000 / 60 / 60),
    ':',
    Math.floor((agora - inicio) / 1000 / 60 % 60)
  ].join('')
); // 17h13m neste momento
```

Comment: _e assumindo que a formatação é aceite isso vai dar a hora exata no inicio desse dia, ao milisegundo_.  **Muito bem** Apesar da resposta responder a minha pergunta, a resposta do Randrade me dá aquilo que eu não perguntei, mas que também preciso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Essa comparação está correcta pois o `new Date()` retorna `Tue Jul 04 2017 16:53:25 GMT+0100 (Hora de Verão de GMT)` e `new Date('07/04/2017')` retorna `Tue Jul 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de Verão de GMT)`

Se reparar as horas são diferentes nos dois usos da data, pois sempre que cria uma nova "data" `new Date()` a grosso modo está a criar uma variável com o mes/dia/ano e horas-minutos-segundos actuais.

Caso crie uma data sem indicar as horas `new Date('04/04/2017'`) irá ser atribuído a esta data as horas-minutos-segundos o valor 0.

Também pode definir a data com `new Date('04/04/2017 01:00'`)

Podes obter o resultado que desejas com.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);

if (d > new Date('07/04/2017'))
{
     alert('Hoje é maior que hoje?')
}
```